# How to concatenate a list of tuples into a list of concatenated item from the tuples in python?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples and i want to make a list of simple strings made of each concatenation of the items in the tuples. I.e:

```
a = [("as","b","c"),("d","e"),("f","g")]
```

b would be = `["as b c","d e","f g"]`

I tried this one:

```
b = [sum(i,[]) for i in a ]
```

but i got

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str" to tuple)`
```

Answer (score 6):

To join multiple strings by spaces, you should use `str.join()`.  It takes a bit getting used to, since you call it on the string you want to use to join the other strings, in this case the space character:

```
>>> map(" ".join, a)
['as b c', 'd e', 'f g']
```

Some people prefer a list comprehension for this:

```
[" ".join(t) for t in a]
```

Comment: I am getting disappointed on my knowledge in python while struggling to find a solution and sometimes it's just so "piece of cake"

Comment: @curious: I recommend taking the time to read through the [documentation of the basic data types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html).  It will pay off.